# Dotless recursive compiling

Tags: .net, dotless

When using dotless for compiling less-files into min.css files. Is there any way to have the compiler check for all .less files in a certain filearea and then compile these into a single css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up with me doing this in a controller that uses the less-dll to do the compiling myself. I then call the controller to get the fully functional, compiled css. Parts of my code below:

```
    protected void SetStringToLessFileFromAllWidgets()
    {
        var widgets = widgetInfoReader.GetWidgetsAvailable();

        foreach (var widget in widgets)
        {
            string cssLocation = widget.FullPath + "\\CSS\\Widget.less.css";
            AppendToStringBuilder(cssLocation);
        }
    }

    public string ParseAndReturnCSSFile()
    {
        cssString = Less.Parse(sb.ToString(), config);
        return cssString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a less file that imports all the files in the folder and compile that.

**Example**

base.less

```
@import url(streaky.less);
@import url(smokey.less);
@import url(back.less);
@import url(bacon.less);
```

Comment: This creates a need to know which files are present in the file area. Since Im creating a website with widgets, that are compiled in to a certain folder I wouldnt know this. See my answer below.